# Tkinter Canvas Image Isn't Showing No Matter What I Do

Tags: python, image, class, tkinter, canvas

So I've been trying to have an image of a pie chart slice display as part of a canvas to absolutely no avail. I'm fine with changing the fundamental structure of the program itself, I just need to know how what the issue is and how to make it work in a class. If possible, I'd also like to know a bit more about how canvas images work since I plan on making a full chart using slices, and almost all sources I've looked up, including the lessons from my college class, were incredibly lacking in specifics regarding syntax and what's possible when it comes to stuff like create_image.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CircleFrame():
    def __init__(self, the_window):
        frame1 = Frame(width=400, height=400, bg="white")
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        canvas1 = Canvas(frame1, width=400, height=400, bg="blue")
        canvas1.pack()
    def primaryCircle(self, canvas1):
        # These 3 lines are what I have been toying with primarily
        sprite1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="10_Slice_2.png")
        canvas1.image = sprite1
        canvas1.create_image(200,200,image=sprite1)



class TextFrame():
    def __init__(self, the_window):
        frame2 = Frame(width=350, height=400, bg="grey")
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        canvas2 = Canvas(frame2, width=350, height=400, bg="red")
        canvas2.pack()



###################################################################
# Main Program
###################################################################

width = 750
height = 400

window = Tk()
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))
window.title("Placeholder Name")

create = CircleFrame(window)
create2 = TextFrame(window)

window.mainloop
```

Basically, the program itself works perfectly fine, no errors, however the image just won't appear on the left canvas.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling `primaryCircle` anywhere. You might need a `create.primaryCircle` somewhere (with a bit of refactoring to pass `canvas1` through)

Comment: Ok so I managed to get the image to appear by omitting the function entirely, it seemed to just be an error in logic. Thank you though for the advice, It probably would've taken me much longer to realize my mistake without your tip!